# htaccess redirect if URL end with 5 numbers

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect, using `.htaccess`, the following matching URLs:

Old URL:

1. `www.example.com/en/product-12345`
2. `www.example.com/en/product-brand-12345`
3. `www.example.com/de/product-12345`
4. `www.example.com/de/product-brand-12345`

New URLs:

1. `www.example.com/en/category/product-12345`
2. `www.example.com/en/category/product-brand-12345`
3. `www.example.com/de/category/product-12345`
4. `www.example.com/de/category/product-brand-12345`

As you can see all the URLs that need to be redirected, are URLs that end with 5 numbers.

The URLs should be redirected by adding `/category/` at the beginning of the URL.

Hope you can help me to find a solution.

Have tried some combinations, but didn't work at all so far.

Comment: Have you tried something like `RewriteRule ^en/product-(.*)$ /en/category/product-$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: "Have tried some combinations, but didn't work at all so far." - Please show what you have tried. And _where_ in your `.htaccess` file you have put these directives - the order is important.

Comment: I assume `product` and `product-band` are variable? In your examples, the URL doesn't only end in 5 digits, but a hyphen (`-`) followed by 5 digits - is that always the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The url's should be redirected with adding /category/ at the beginning of the url.

In your examples, you are not adding `/category/` at the beginning of the URL, but in the middle, between the "language" and "product-slug" path segments.

You could do something like the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/([a-z-]+-\d{5})$ /$1/category/$2 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the language code (either `en` or `de`) captured from the requested URL-path. And `$2` is the "product-slug" (a single path segment) that ends in `-NNNNN` (where `N` is a digit 0-9).

I've assumed the "product-slug" before the `-NNNNN` part can consist of lowercase letters a-z and a hyphen only (as per your examples).

Test with a 302 (temp) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and make sure you have cleared your browser cache before testing.

Answer (score 0):

@MrWhite: thanks for your answer! You were right about the fact that the URLs were not beginning with `/category/`

Furthermore, I have used your excellent input combined with the other input to find the correct redirect.

This is the one we came up with which works perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de|ar|es|fr|nl|pl|pt|ru|tr|ro)/([^/]+)-(\d{5})$ /$1/category/$2-$3 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: There's no need for two capturing subpatterns (ie. `$2` and `$3`) in the last path segment. As shown in my answer, only one is required here. If you have many languages then it may be simpler (and more scalable) to just match any 2 letters. You probably should not be using the `NC` flag here unless uppercase language codes are valid (but then you potentially have a duplicate content issue). For example: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+-\d{5})$ /$1/category/$2 [R=301,L]`